# Mute Android from HTML 5 web page

Tags: android, html, audio, notifications, mute

I would like to place a 'button/icon' on a web page. This button/icon when pressed/tapped on an Android device will need to mute all Android alarms, notifications, and sound.

Ideally, I want the button (coded in HTML) to enact the code that tells Android to turns its sounds off.

I have been trying to find the answer to my question but everything I find deals with how to mute the sound of players embedded on web pages or similar.
As a last resort, I thought to ask my question here to see if somebody knows what I do not.

Thank you,

TagMan